# Cannot compile ScalaCheck with specs2 since upgrading

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2, sbt-assembly, scalacheck

I used to use:

```
"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
```

Which worked fine, then I upgraded my dependencies to what I think are the latest:

```
"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
"org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.4.15" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
```

Which should be correct according to http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/

But now `ScalaCheck` is not being recognised as a member of `org.specs2`

```
[error] /Users/me/src/aFile.scala:7: object ScalaCheck is not a member of package org.specs2
[error] import org.specs2.ScalaCheck
[error]        ^
```

I've done `sbt clean` and removed by ivy cache `rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the specs2-scalacheck module to your build.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong, you need to add multiple SBT lines to the build file, in particular add one according to Erics answer.

Also do NOT add the following, it causes a bunch of other errors

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.15" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
```